# Where are official build system generator name mentioned for different versions of Microsoft Visual Studio for CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Lot of open source softwares use [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) for generating build files for [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation). Generally we do like

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64"
```

Here we are passing `Visual Studio 15 2017` as `build system generator name`.
Different project recommend different versions of Visual Studio. I could not find these names for different versions on `CMake` documentation.

For example for `Visual Studio 2019` generator name is `Visual Studio 16 2019`
Where can I find these names for `-G` option for different version or How can I construct generator name myself?

Comment: Do a `cmake --help` on the command line and all supported generators on this platform are listed.

Comment: And for further information consult the CMake documentation for generators https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html